# Disabled checkbox for QTreeWidget

Tags: select, pyqt, qtreewidget, qcheckbox

Does anyone know how to make an uneditable checkbox ina  QTreeWidgetItem but keep the QTreeWidgetItem selectable?

Comment: For anyone interested this is done with **QTreeWidgetItem.setFlags( Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled )**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set the flag `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` of the item, but set the `checkState` to `Qt.Checked` or `Qt.Unchecked`.

The presence of a checkbox and the user checkability are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setCheckState(0,Qt::Checked);
```